# How to get category list in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
get_the_category_list();
wp_list_categories();
```

Above functions are not working in my project.
I can't get new created categories in wordpress.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please read [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Before posting, ***you are expected to have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself***. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, I will noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

I recommend using get_terms

```
  $terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
   'hide_empty' => false,
  ) );
```